# bash/command line: How to copy several files in different directories at once

Tags: bash, command-line, copy

I am trying to copy a file (let's call it list.txt) that is in several places and give it a new name. Some folders should be ignored (e.g. those containing _old)

Assume the following structure:

```
/data/folder1/subfolder/user/list.txt
/data/folder2/subfolder/user/list.txt
/data/folder2/subfolder_old/user/list.txt
/data/folder3/anothername/other/list.txt
/data/folder3/anothername/ignorethisfolder/list.txt
```

With following command I get the exact files listed that I expect:

```
ll /data/*/{subfolder,anothername}/{user,other}/*.txt 2>/dev/null
```

That's what I want to use for copying and the following:

```
cp /data/*/{subfolder,anothername}/{user,other}/*.txt /data/*/{subfolder, anothername}/{user,other}/*.txt_backup 2>/dev/null
```

---

**Unfortunately, this does not deliver the desired result.
What should the command for the copying process be?**

Comment: This might help: [How to copy a file to multiple folders using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/432795/336375)

Comment: Why do you have a space in your `cp` command in front of _anothername_?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `cp` command doesn't work that way, you need to copy each file independently:

```bash
for f in /data/*/{subfolder,anothername}/{user,other}/*.txt
do
    cp "$f" "${f}_backup"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the find command:

`find /data -not -path "*/*_old/*" -name "list.txt" -type f -exec cp {} {}_backup \;`

**Explanation**

1. `find /data` traverse your /data directory
2. `-not -path "*/*_old/*"` exclude any paths with a directory ending in _old
3. `-name "list.txt"` select files/directories with the name list.txt
4. `-type f` only select files
5. `-exec cp {} {}_backup \;` execute cp on all remaining matching paths the {} is replaced with the match path and the ; is needed to end the exec statement

**note**
You can add your `2>/dev/null` if you still get errors on some results.